# Manipulate check_box values before saving the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, checkbox

I have a model Fruit with 4 attributes `:name, :characteristic1 ,:characteristic2,:characteristic3`. In fruits table `:characteristic1 ,:characteristic2,:characteristic3` fields will receive values from the 6 checkboxes (because i didn't want to add all 6 fields to a fruit table) in the form that a user will have to pick only 3 of them.How would i get the values selected in the checkboxes and insert them in `:characteristic1 ,:characteristic2,:characteristic3` ,without forgeting  :name field that accepts input as text_field?I am sure this has to be done in the controller but i dont know how.Thank you in advance.

form

```
      <%= form_for @fruit ,:url=>{:action =>"create"} do |f| %>
      <%=f.text_field :name %>

      <%=f.fields_for :characteristics do |c| %>
        <!--Characteristics checkboxes -->
        <%end%>
       <%=f.submit "submit" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would tell you to create 2 new models: Characteristic and FruitCharacteristic

Fruit would have many characteristics trough fruitCharacteristic

And read this api page to find something cool to solve the form problem

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html

**UPDATE:**
This should work for many-to-many

```
<ul>
   <% Characteristic.all.each do |c| %>
      <li><%= check_box_tag :characteristics_ids, c.id, @fruit.characteristics.include?(c), :name => 'fruit[characteristics_ids][]' %>
      <%= label_tag :characteristics_ids, c.name %></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid doing that, i just wanted something simple,if possible.

Comment: In your way it's hard to guarantee consistence and for example find all fruits with specific characteristics will also be hard.

Comment: I didnt want to do many to many association because it gets too complex.Is it a normal practice to add 30 fields to a database table?

Comment: I think you are just cuting complexity in one place and adding at other.

Comment: I  tried to do has_many through relationship but i was stuck on how to set up the form.I have edit the form above, can you show me how i would set up the check_boxes please?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to restrict user to selecting only 3 categories, it is better to provide 3 select boxes/3 sets of check boxes along the line of something like "characteristic1", "characteristic2" and "characteristic3". Then in the controller, you can simply access the values using params[:fruit][:characteristic1] and so on.